# App crashed when captured image

Tags: java, android, image, cursor

What's wrong with my code? I have a simple camera function in my app and it can use to `choose image from gallery` and `take photo`. Everything working fine just the **captured image cannot be retrieved out**.

**Claims.java** (insert image)

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if ((name != null && name.trim().length() > 0) && (result != null && result.trim().length() > 0)) {
                   // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fk+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    byte[] data=getBitmapAsByteArray(Global.img); // this is a function
                    if(data==null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        SB.insertStaffBenefit(name, data, description, result, fk);
                    }

            }

        });
        return claims;
    }
```

**ViewView.java** (One of the navigation item )

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
                String ID =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));

                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewView.this.getActivity(), Receipt.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Receipt.java**

```
public class Receipt extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private Cursor c;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.receipt);
        dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
        final String k = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), k+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        RetrieveImage(k);
}

    public void RetrieveImage(String b)
    {
        ImageView a=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        c = database.rawQuery("SELECT s.Image FROM Information i LEFT JOIN StaffBenefit s ON s.Twd_id=i._id WHERE i._id=? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(b)},null);
        if(c!=null)
        {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
               byte[] img=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Image"));
                if(img!=null)
                {
                    Log.e("TAG", " Not null");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("TAG", " null");
                }
                ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
                Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                a.setImageBitmap(theImage);

            }
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Image selected from gallery can be retrieved out to `a` in **Receipt.java**, but app crashed if the captured image trying to retrieved out and display on `a`.

```
Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 26303
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project.project/com.example.project.project.Receipt}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from
CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
accessing data from it.
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
         at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
         at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:404)
         at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
         at com.example.project.project.Receipt.RetrieveImage(Receipt.java:43)
         at com.example.project.project.Receipt.onCreate(Receipt.java:32)
```

**(Receipt.java:43)**

```
  byte[] img=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Image"));
```

**(Receipt.java:32)**

```
RetrieveImage(k);
```

**WHY it works for `choosing image from gallery`, but not `taking photo`? Isn't because the image not successfully inserted ?**

Comment: I think your cursor has only 1 column so try to call the first row data

Comment: @MohammadAbuQauod but it works for `choosing image from gallery`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `cursor.moveToFirst()` . Move the cursor position at first and remove `while loop` (i don't think it's needed).

```
if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
           byte[] img=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Image"));
            if(img!=null)
            {
                Log.e("TAG", " Not null");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("TAG", " null");
            }
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
            Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            a.setImageBitmap(theImage);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change your code like this

```
     if(c!=null)
                {
if (!c.isAfterLast())
                    while (c.moveToFirst()) {
                       byte[] img=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Image"));
                        if(img!=null)
                        {
                            Log.e("TAG", " Not null");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("TAG", " null");
                        }
                        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
                        Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        a.setImageBitmap(theImage);

                    }
    c.moveToNext();
                }
                c.close();
```